# Angular 2 Change detection in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Im taking a look at the Angular 2 beta and im struggling with how the change detection works. Ive made a simple plunkr example which shows an issue i am experiencing.

```js
//our root app component
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public state: boolean = true;
  
  change() {
    this.state = false;
    console.log(this.state);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <p>{{state}}</p>
      <button (click)="doLogout()" class="btn btn-success">logout</button>
      <button (click)="changeName()" class="btn btn-success">change name</button>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class App {
  constructor(_auth: AuthService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this._auth = _auth;
    this.state = _auth.state;
  }
  
  doLogout() {
    this._auth.change();
  }
  
  changeName() {
    this.name = "something else";
  }
}
```

When you press the logout button i am updating the state value in the AuthService. I would expect the view to update its shown value aswell, but it stays as true, when it should update to false. The printed console value is correct however.

https://plnkr.co/edit/CJBjRvyO9aSV0SSHm66R?p=preview

Could someone please explain why it doesnt work, and how i may fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only assigning `this.state` once - in the constructor when the `App` component is created. Later changes are not reflected.

You might want to bind to `<p>{{_auth.state}}</p>` instead or subscribe to an `EventEmitter` in the service and update `state` every time the value is updated in the service. See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/o88z1FFYcZsNebbcGBsF?p=preview) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an angular 2 problem. Angular detects changes in references and that's not not a reference:

```
this.state = _auth.state;
```

Change by this:

```
{{_auth.state}}
```